# Windows 8.1 opens IE even though Chrome is default browser. Can I change?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, browser

I'm sure its a Windows issue, not a matter of certain programs being hardcoded to use IE (as suggested here) because... well, its Google's Picassa (among others) that's launching IE and if any program would NOT be hardcoded to launch IE, it would be a Google product :)

Chrome is my browser and it is set as default, yet anytime a system event launches a browser it does it in IE.  How to change?

Comment: You don't.  I assume your using the current version?

Comment: Was that default set in the same account or was it set in the admin account and now you operate in a user account. Note:  Default program settings are per account.

Comment: I have only one account.